# How to git add all files excluding a certain folder, from anywhere in a repo?

Tags: linux, bash, git, github, bitbucket

I would like to create an alias that adds all modified files to the staging area, excluding any changes in extern/.

`git add .` will add all modified files and `git add --all -- ':!extern/*'` will add all modified files **except** anything in `extern/`. But that will only work if you are in the same directory as the extern (at the top level of the repo) folder. I don't know how to do this from anywhere in the repo, like from several directories deep.

I was wondering if there was an elegant way to reference the top level of the repo i.e. something like `git add --all -- ':![top_level_of_repo]/extern/*'`.

Comment: In fact, there *is* pathspec magic for "top". You can use (top), or as in larsks' answer, the single character `/`, which I think reads a lot easier. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-C` argument to git to change directory, and use `git rev-parse` to get the top level of the repository:

```
git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) add --all -- ':!extern/*'
```

...or, having just read the `gitglossary(7)` entry on `pathspec`, it looks like you could actually just write:

```
git add --all -- ':!/extern/*'
```

Comment: Ill give that a try but wouldn't `/` start you at the root directory on the linux server you are on?

Comment: It does not. Take a look at the `gitglossary` man page.